# adding double quotes to the last field in a file using unix commands

Tags: linux

I have a requirement to ingest application logs to Splunk which has format as below
Format of the file - comma delimited file
field1, field2, field3, field4, field5. Field5 has special characters like newline characters, embedded commas, double quotes etc. Now I need to enclose this field in double quotes and escape any special characters in the value.
I tried using sed & awk to enclose field in double quotes to the last field by escaping special characters in the value.

No luck. If someone could shed some light would be a great help.

Sample Data from actual log file

```
abc,def,ghi,jkl,###abcjkl, defghi"ifgnhgt", NOSQL
executed sql 
abc|def|ghi|68
abc|jkl|opg|78
INFO: (Sql statement: select col1, col2, col3 from table_schema.table_name)
abc,def,ghi,jkl,####oprght, hghihk"lklmnp", PostgreSQL
executed sql
select col1,
col2,
col3 
from table_schema.table_name
abc,def,ghi,jkl,####user1@mail.com, user2@mail.com, user3@mail.com,
user4@mail.com
abc, def, ghi,jkl, ###      PID:238876   ###
```

Trying to get into below format

```
abc,def,ghi,jkl,"###abcjkl, defghi\\"ifgnhgt\\", NOSQL
executed sql 
abc|def|ghi|68
abc|jkl|opg|78
INFO: (Sql statement: select col1, col2, col3 from table_schema.table_name)"
abc,def,ghi,jkl,"####oprght, hghihk\\"lklmnp\\", PostgreSQL
executed sql
select col1,
col2,
col3 
from table_schema.table_name"
abc,def,ghi,jkl,"####user1@mail.com, user2@mail.com, user3@mail.com,
user4@mail.com"
abc, def, ghi,jkl, "###      PID:238876   ###"
```

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Could be something like:

```
perl -ne '
  sub process {
    if (defined($before)) {
      chomp $after;
      printf qq(%s"%s"\n), $before, $after =~ s/"/\\\\"/gr
    }
  }
  if (/^([^,]*,){4}\h*\K###.*/s) {
    process;
    $before = $`; $after = $&
  } else {
    $after .= $_
  }
  END{process}' < your-file
```

Where we look for lines with at least 4 commas, the fourth of which followed by optional `\h`orizontal whitespace and `###` to identify the start of each record.